# Interpretating IRF correctly

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

We have following Impulse Response Function:

```
# Load data and apply VAR
library("vars")
data(Canada)
data <- Canada
data <- data.frame(data[,1:2])
var <- VAR(data, p=3, type = "both")
plot(irf(var, impulse = "e", response = "prod", boot = T, cumulative = FALSE, n.ahead = 20, ci=0.95))
```

Output:

[image: Impulse Response]

Now I want to make sure to give the right interpretation here:

1. The orthogonal response of *prod* after an impulse of *e* is the highest at lag 3.
2. A **1%** increase of *e* causes a **15%** increase of *prod* at lag 3.
3. With a 95% confidence, the response value of *prod* for a 1% increase of *e* is between -15% and +35%, meaning that it is not 100% positive. It's only that the largest part of the confidence interval that is positive.
4. Otherwise, the response of *prod* after an 1% impulse of *e* is negative from lag 6-20+. It's particularly negative at lags 10-15. The cumulative IRF is therefore also negative for the observed lags.

Are these observations correct?

Bonus quiz:
5. If I multiply all the values (irf, or here on the axis) by 100, what do I get then?